# regex to mysql regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I am searching for a way to replace and update a string value in MySQL starting or ending with a percentage.

I would like values like the following:

```
'15 % flour'
' 15 % beef'
'15% pork'
' 15 % rice'
'eggplant 15 %'
'banana 15 % '
'turkey 15%'
'chicken 15% '
```

In all these examples I would like to end out with only the ingredient.
Ex: flour or beef

I found out that this will remove the percentage if in the starting of the line.
REGEXP_REPLACE(ingredient_name, '^([0-9]|100)+(\%)+', '')
But not if there is space between the number and the percentage symbol.

This was my best try, but I found out it wasn't compatible with Mysql regexp_replace.

```
\d+((' '|\s|\b)\%(' '|\s|$))
```

[test link](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=108064)

Comment: Try `' *[0-9]+ *% *'` or `'[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*%[[:space:]]*'`. What is the MySQL version?

Comment: Or try `[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]*%[[:blank:]]*`

Comment: Try replacing `^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$` or `^[^[:alpha:]]+|[^[:alpha:]]+$` with empty string to see if this regex is supported in your mysql version. What's your mysql version though?

Comment: Both `[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*%[[:space:]]*`, `[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]*%[[:blank:]]*` and `^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$` seems to work. Whats the difference?

Comment: `^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$` < This one removed national special characters in my ingredients. Therefore `[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*%[[:space:]]*` seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `[[:space:]]*` to match 0 or more whitespace chars between the number and `%`:

```
'[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*%[[:space:]]*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkwATa/1).

It matches

- `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `%` - a `%` char
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespace chars

Note that neither `\d` nor `\s` and `\b` might not be supported if your MySQL version is older than 8.x.